# Gwibber Twitter "Authorise" button does nothing when clicked

Tags: proxy, gwibber, twitter

I've had this issue since 11.10, the authorise button literally does nothing when pressed in Gwibber so I can't add an account or anything.

I am behind a proxy so I fear this may be an issue? I see no options to edit a proxy specifically in Gwibber, everything else is set up with the proxy and works fine (firefox, pidgin etc)

Answer (score 1):

I've "solved" this problem starting gwibber in a terminal : just type "gwibber" and click on the authorise button.

But once the account set, I can't receive news, the F5 button don't do anything... Any idea?

PS. Sorry for my English, I'm French :)